# Ubuntu 22.04 using gnome-session-flashback top panel has lost Applications and Places icons, and bottom panel randomly reorganises icons

Tags: 22.04, panel, gnome-classic, gnome-flashback

I am running Ubuntu 22.04, but like the classic menu look, so run with gnome-session-flashback. The other day, something happened, and the Application and Places icons disappeared. In addition, on the bottom panel, at random intervals, I can suddenly see the icons rearrange (maybe to their original order). I have read extensively, and not seen this issue at all.

I tried `sudo apt remove gnome-session-flashback` and `sudo apt purge gnome-session-flashback`, and restarting the laptop before reinstalling with `sudo apt install gnome-session-flashback`, and then the Application and places icons are still missing, and the bottom panel still behaves randomly.

It may be coincidental, but `gnome-panel` also seems to crash before the bottom panel re-sorts itself.

Any help would be most appreciated.

[Edit]: I checked the `dconf` setting for gnome-panel, and found it to be corrupted, so I copied the entry from another laptop with the same display and replaced the corrupted instance of `/org/gnome/gnome-panel/layout/object-id-list` with a correct version having checked the other ares of `/org/gnome/gnome-panel/layout` are correct and exist, yet once updated, the settings seem to be corrupted again.

This is the behaviour I expect from Windows, and is the first basic issue I have had with Ubuntu, and I really don't want to have to reinstall Ubuntu.

Any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: Can you get [stack trace](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/GettingInTouch/Bugzilla/GettingTraces) and open new issue [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-panel/-/issues)?

Comment: Many thanks for your guidance, but the information for Ubuntu 22.04 indicates that I would need to run e.g. gdb -q <program> but I am not running any program - it is (I surmise) the shell.
Are you able to guide me further? My apologies for being non-technical!
Many thanks,